# How to stop ignore_user_abort once started?

Tags: php

Whats the best solution to stop a ignore_user_abort actively running on the server in a loop? (PHP)

Basically trying to stop a infinitely looping PHP script that won't stop because ignore_user_abort was set and the script executed ..

Simple exaggerated example  :

```
<? 

ignore_user_abort(true);

set_time_limit(0);

$test = 1;

while ($test < 1000000000000000 )

{

sleep(1);
$test = $test+1;
}

?>
```

Comment: In what context? Do you mean stop it in your script? Or are you asking how to kill an infinitely looping PHP script that won't stop because `ignore_user_abort` was turned on?

Comment: Please provide more information showing some sample code. Are you able to do exit();?

Comment: Example added ...
exit(); wont work because its actively running..

Comment: Still don't have a solution to this apart from restarting Apache to kill the process ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems [`connection_aborted`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) is what you're looking for?

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);

while (TRUE) {
  if(connection_aborted()) {
      break;
  }
  sleep(5);
}

// do some stuff now that we know the connection is gone
?>
```

Alternatively you could check [`connection_status`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php) against the predefined `CONNECTION_ABORTED` constant:

```
if(connection_status() == CONNECTION_ABORTED)
{
    break;
}
```

You can get a good rundown in the [manual docs on Connection handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking. What are you trying to do that a simple break or exit can't accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

```
//this will stop the script after running for  30 sec
set_time_limit(30);
```